# Удаление отдельного объекта из localStorage по кнопке

Tags: javascript

Человек добавляет товары в корзину. По кнопке "купить" на странице товара он сохраняет ID'шник товара, подвязанный к кнопке, в localStorage. Далее, массивом, ID'шник(-ки) отправляются на бэкенд post-запросом, откуда потом страница корзины получает данные из БД и отрисовывает их динамически на странице.

Вопрос в том, как теперь удалить ненужный товар из хранилища. Удаление именно со страницы по нажатию кнопки есть, а вот как по нажатию на эту же кнопку добавить удаление нужного товара из lS, на ум не приходит...

Код-отправки

```
$.post("/answer",
    {data: data_id_prod},
    function (response) {
        let chill = response.id_prod
        console.log(chill);
        let j = 0
    
        $.each(chill, function(key, value) {
            j++
            var new_div = document.createElement('ul');

            new_div.className = ('prod_in_cart' +[j])
            new_div.innerHTML = (value.ID + ' \n ' + value.product_name + ' \n ' + value.product_price + ' рублей');
            new_div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '\n<button class = "remove">X</button>');
            divvv.appendChild(new_div);
            //document.getElementById('remove').onclick = removeElement;

            const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');

            buttons.forEach(button => {
                button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                   //button.parentElement.remove()
                   window.localStorage.removeItem()
                });
            });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: вы уверены, что вам нужен jquery ?  а то кроме коротких $.post и $.each вы его не используете хотя можно было весь код нормально написать и сократить раза в 2.

Comment: уберите это навешивание кликов на кнопки удаления из поста, наверх туда через `$("#wrapper").on("click", ".remove", function(){ .... })` И никто вам не скажет, как удалить элементы из хранилища, покак не узнает в каком виде вы их туда записываете.

Comment: Ну удаляйте по ключу, по которому добавляли. В чём проблема? Можете записать `id` в `data` аттрибут кнопкам и по клику забирать этот `id` и удалять

Comment: @EzioMercer, я новичок, поэтому не особо понимаю, почему вы предлагаете засунуть атрибут кнопок в отправляемые данные? (data_id_prod - массив с данными, который одноразово улетает на бэкенд, ничего не возвращая).

Comment: @Awake Я не сказал засунуть аттрибут кнопок в отправляемые данные. Я сказал засунуть `id` продкута в [data аттрибут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) кнопки